# Rspec and Rails NoMethodError for comparison operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am testing a User model with the following spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do

  it "password length to be equal to or greater than 8 characters" do
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:user, password: '12345678')).to be >= 8
  end

end
```

The Factory looks like this:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |f|
    f.name      {Faker::Name.name}
    f.email     {Faker::Internet.email}
    f.password  {Faker::Internet.password(8)}
  end
end
```

I added this line to my rails_helper:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

I have the following gems installed:

```
Using rspec-support 3.2.2
Using rspec-core 3.2.3
Using rspec-expectations 3.2.1
Using rspec-mocks 3.2.1
Using rspec 3.2.0
Using rspec-rails 3.2.1
Using factory_girl 4.5.0
Using factory_girl_rails 4.5.0
Using faker 1.4.3
```

When I execute the test, I keep getting the following error:

```
1) User password length to be equal to or greater than 8 characters
     Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.build(:user, password: '12345678')).to be >= 8
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `>=' for #<User:0x007fe097d35ea8>
```

I've checked the documentation [API Docs](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-2/docs/built-in-matchers), and I think this is the proper way, however, I am new to rspec. Please advise if I need to provide more documentation. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `password` should be `>= 8` not the `user object` so it should be something like this

```
expect(FactoryGirl.build(:user, password: '12345678').password.to_s.length).to be >= 8
```

Comment: Thanks Raj for the response, I tried that. Please see my reply to Marcus.

Comment: `.password.length` did you use it?